# Cadence Activity metrics not being emitted

Tags: java, cadence-workflow, uber-cadence

In my cadence client, I have workflow service and workflow client variables which are able to emit metrics to my scope

```
 this.workflowService = new WorkflowServiceTChannel(cadenceHost, cadencePort, new WorkflowServiceTChannel.ClientOptions.Builder()
                .setMetricsScope(this.metricsScope)
                .build());
        this.workflowClient = WorkflowClient.newInstance(this.workflowService, domain, new WorkflowClientOptions.Builder()
                .setDataConverter(dataConverter)
                .setMetricsScope(this.metricsScope)
                .build());
        this.completionClient = workflowClient.newActivityCompletionClient();
```

I am able to see metrics like `workflow-endtoend-latency`. I am also able to see metrics for `activity-task-completed` as this is emitted when completion client is called.

I am similarly creating my workers using worker options with the same metric scope, however, I am not able to see any `activity-endtoend-latency`, `activity-execution-latency` etc. I am able to see `activity-scheduled-to-start-latency`, and activity poll related metrics.

This is code for creating my workers

```
WorkerOptions workerOptions = new WorkerOptions.Builder()
                .setDataConverter(dataConverter)
                .setWorkflowPollerOptions(new PollerOptions.Builder()
                                                  .setPollThreadCount(pollerThreadCount)
                                                  .build())
                .setActivityPollerOptions(new PollerOptions.Builder()
                                                  .setPollThreadCount(pollerThreadCount)
                                                  .build())
                .setMaxConcurrentWorkflowExecutionSize(concurrentExecutionSize)
                .setMaxConcurrentActivityExecutionSize(concurrentExecutionSize)
                .setMaxConcurrentLocalActivityExecutionSize(concurrentExecutionSize)
                .setMetricsScope(this.metricsScope)
                .build();
Worker worker = factory.newWorker(taskList, workerOptions);
```

and this is how I start my activities

```
ActivityOptions activityOptions = new ActivityOptions.Builder()
                .setRetryOptions(retryOptions)
                .setTaskList(taskList)
                .setStartToCloseTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(timeoutSeconds))
                .setScheduleToCloseTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(timeoutSeconds))
                .build();
ActivityStub stub = Workflow.newUntypedActivityStub(activityOptions);
stub.execute(activityName, Object.class, args);
```

How do I get my client to send me the activity execution latency metrics as well ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an statsd issue actually. All my metrics which tagged ActivityType were having this issue. My ActivityType was like this `some:prefix::activity_name` , and statsd has issues with `:` being inside the metric definition itself https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/issues/547